# alcohol percentage

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have two types of beer:

> Bravia $\$3.50$ each, $8.6\%$ alcohol, $500$ ml
>   Moosehead $\$2.08$ each, $5\%$ alcohol, $335$ ml

am I right to say:

> One Bravia has 43 ml alcohol
>   One Moosehead has 16.75 ml alcohol

then:

> One Bravia costs $12.28$ cents per ml of alcohol
>   One Moosehead costs $8.05$ cents per ml of alcohol

My question is if my calculations are correct here and that Moosehead is the better buy if looking for the most alcohol for my dollar. I hope my question is straight forward, I'm really unsure how to go about calculating how much alcohol is in each of the two beer and which is the better buy given I wanted to buy the one with the most alcohol for my money.

What I'm really looking for is help understanding how to calculate this for my self, thanks.

Comment: Is it really valid to call a beer "better buy" just because it has more alcohol?

Comment: no peterwhy it's not. But I'm not actually trying to pick out a beer, I'm trying to find out how to calculate which beer has more alchool for it's money.

Comment: Did you calculated the cents per ml of alcohol wrongly?

Comment: @peterwhy It all depends on circumstances. Calculating it this way makes sense if you were buying cheap beer to distil the alcohol for industrial use. If you were trying to get drunk this calculation would not be ideal since a beer with low ABV might be impossible to drink fast enough for the expected level of intoxication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calculation can be performed by first converting the alcohol percent concentration into a decimal.  For Moosehead, that would be 5% = 0.05.  Then multiply 0.05 by the volume in a bottle: 
$$0.05 \cdot 335 \ ml = 16.75 \ ml \ of \ alcohol \ in \ 1 \ bottle \ of \ Moosehead $$

(which you performed correctly in your above calculations).  Then you can divide the cost of the beer by the amount of alcohol per bottle to get the price per ml alcohol: 
$$\frac{208 \ cents}{16.75}=$0.12 \ per \  ml \ alcohol $$

Perform this same calculation for Bravia to compare the values of the beers.  You'll find that Bravia is the greater value.